# How To Create MS Word Macro To Check "Bold" + "Without Keep With Next" Paragraphs And Add Comments For Each

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've tried to create a macro to check "bold" + "Without Keep With Next" paragraphs and add comments for each by using macro record function in word application. But it's not work for me.

I need to create a macro for below criteria.

1. Search all bold paragraphs + without keep with next.
2. Then Add comments for each bold + without keep with next. (Ex Comment: Check Keep With Next)

How do I do this.

---------- Edit ----------

See this image for more clarity:

[image]

I've tried.

```
Sub KWN_Checker()

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Font.Bold = True
With Selection.Find.ParagraphFormat
    .KeepWithNext = False
End With
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^p"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
Selection.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range
Selection.TypeText Text:="Check"
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Font.Bold = True
With Selection.Find.ParagraphFormat
    .KeepWithNext = False
End With
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^p"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True

End With
Selection.TypeText Text:=" Keep With Next"
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Font.Bold = True
With Selection.Find.ParagraphFormat
    .KeepWithNext = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
End Sub
```

Comment: SO isn't a coding service. You should first show off what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a more efficient way of doing it, but this will do what you want:

```
   Option Explicit

Sub FncCheckBold()

    Const message As String = "Check Keep With Next"
    Const styleMask As String = "Bold + KWN"
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim paragraphCount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim currentStyle As String

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    paragraphCount = doc.Paragraphs.Count

    Do While i < paragraphCount

        i = i + 1

        If doc.Paragraphs(i).Range.Bold = True Then

            currentStyle = doc.Paragraphs(i).Range.Style

            If Left(currentStyle, Len(styleMask)) <> styleMask Then

                doc.Paragraphs(i).Range.Select
                Selection.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range
                Selection.TypeText Text:=message

            End If

        End If

    Loop

    Set doc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Davy C for your respond this. I've check your code but it's not working for me.

Comment: I've updated the answer. I noticed a couple of problems with the original one. You might want to tighten up the check for "keep with next" by wrapping it in a Ucase or Lcase statement. Hope you can adapt this to your code.

Comment: Thanks Davy, I've check your code. It's not identify "Bold" + "Don't Keep With Next" paragraphs properly. Also I need add comment for each identified items. Please see this image for more clarity. [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LWHrW.png)

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarification (you're original question was a bit sparse). I now see that you are talking about the "style" of the paragraph. I've re-posted code. I'm sure you can figure out how to tweak it if necessary, but this works for me.

Comment: Thanks Davy & sorry for the confusion earlier. Now I think it's works me 95% :) I need to add another search string to skip finding keep with next added bold paragraph. Your code will find all bold paragraphs. But I really need to find bold with keep with next false paragraphs. Can you add this to your code? `KeepWithNext = False` For more info about keep with next: [link](http://www.blurbiness.com/web/sites/default/files/blog/line-and-page-breaks.jpg)

Comment: Also I've read [Searching for words in word, but ignoring tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991705/searching-for-words-in-word-but-ignoring-tables) article from stackoverflow. Can we add this method to your code. I think it'll be better.  Thanks!

Comment: Hello. I feel that I have answered your original question 100%. I think that you have enough info in my code and the link that you just posted to now tweak it according to your latest requirements. I'm here to teach and pick up new things myself, so I'm not in the market for doing free software development ;-) Best of luck, Davy.

Comment: Thanks again Devy for the support. I've change your original code to fulfill my requirement.  `If doc.Paragraphs(i).KeepWithNext = False Then`